# Unwanted java code output

Tags: java, string

The following code:

```
public class CharExp {

   public static String charCount(String [] a){
      String chc="" ;

      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length(); j++) {
            char ch = a[i].charAt(j);
            int charcout = a[i].length();
            chc=  Character.toString(ch)+""+Integer.toString(charcout)+" ";
            //  String chc=  ch + "" + charcout + " ";
            // return chc;  
            System.out.print(chc);
         }
      } 
      System.out.print(chc);
      return null;  
   } 

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String [] umesh= {"1h","xa yb","2h","xax yk zn","3h","5h","6h","2h"};

      for (String umesh1 : umesh) {
         String[] guddi = umesh1.split(" ");
         if((guddi[0].charAt(0)=='1')
            ||(guddi[0].charAt(0)=='2') 
            ||(guddi[0].charAt(0)=='3')  
            ||(guddi[0].charAt(0)=='4')  
            ||(guddi[0].charAt(0)=='5')  
            ||(guddi[0].charAt(0)=='6')  
            ||(guddi[0].charAt(0)=='7'))  {

            String ra1 = guddi[0].replaceAll("1", "v");
            String ra2 = ra1.replaceAll("2", "t");
            String ra3 = ra2.replaceAll("3", "t3");
            String ra4 = ra3.replaceAll("4", "f");
            String ra5 = ra4.replaceAll("5", "f5");
            String ra6 = ra5.replaceAll("6", "s");

            System.out.println(ra6);

         } else {

            {
               for(int j=0; j<guddi.length; j++) {

               }

                charCount(guddi);
            }

         }
      }

   }
}
```

Is giving me the following output:

```
vh
x2 a2 y2 b2 b2 th
x3 a3 x3 y2 k2 z2 n2 n2 t3h
f5h
sh
th
```

In the output of the second line, the repition of `b2` is not required. Similarly, in the third line, repetion of `n2` is unwanted. In other words, the required output should be:

```
vh
x2 a2 y2 b2 th
x3 a3 x3 y2 k2 z2 n2 t3h
f5h
sh
th
```

Further I need the output in a single string as:

```
String str= "vh x2 a2 y2 b2 th x3 a3 x3 y2 k2 z2 n2 t3h f5h sh th"
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the logic of your code?

Comment: It is not easy to tell where the problem is. Did you debug your code?

Comment: i dint understand what you want, can you example what is your input and what is your output?

Comment: Please try to format your code correctly. Also, what have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: What do you want us to do?

Comment: It prints it twice because you told it to print it twice. Try running the code in your head or on paper.

Comment: I think problem is `System.out.print(chc);` you are printing outside the loop. check after removing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you want to achieve with the code but some things are getting printed twice because you are printing them twice.  In your `charCount()`:

```
public static String charCount(String [] a){
  String chc="" ;

  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length(); j++) {
        char ch = a[i].charAt(j);
        int charcout = a[i].length();
        chc=  Character.toString(ch)+""+Integer.toString(charcout)+" ";
        //  String chc=  ch + "" + charcout + " ";
        // return chc;  
        System.out.print(chc);
     }
  } 
  // The next line is the problem. Why do you print here?
  System.out.print(chc);
  return null;  
  }
```

Also learn some basics of functions. You are definiting a return type function and returning `null`? If you just want to print, make the function `void`.

To get the output in a single string define a string in the beginning and concatenate every result in it. Is it that tough?

**EDIT:**

The following is the code as you required. Please note, there are much better ways to do this stuff but I am giving the simplest given the fact that you're a beginner.

```
public class CharExp {
    private static String final_output="";
    public static void charCount(String [] a){
        String chc="" ;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length(); j++) {
                char ch = a[i].charAt(j);
                int charcout = a[i].length();
                chc=  Character.toString(ch)+""+Integer.toString(charcout)+" ";
                final_output += chc + " ";
            }
        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String [] stringlist= {"1h","xa yb","2h","xax yk zn","3h","5h","6h","2h"};
        for (String string : stringlist) 
        {
            String[] splitted_list = string.split(" ");
            if((splitted_list[0].charAt(0)=='1')
            ||(splitted_list[0].charAt(0)=='2') 
            ||(splitted_list[0].charAt(0)=='3')  
            ||(splitted_list[0].charAt(0)=='4')  
            ||(splitted_list[0].charAt(0)=='5')  
            ||(splitted_list[0].charAt(0)=='6')  
            ||(splitted_list[0].charAt(0)=='7'))  
            {
                String ra1 = splitted_list[0].replaceAll("1", "v");
                ra1 = ra1.replaceAll("2", "t");
                ra1 = ra1.replaceAll("3", "t3");
                ra1 = ra1.replaceAll("4", "f");
                ra1 = ra1.replaceAll("5", "f5");
                ra1 = ra1.replaceAll("6", "s");
                final_output += ra1 + " ";
            } 
            else 
            {
                charCount(splitted_list);
            }
        }
        System.out.print(final_output);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have pinpointed my mistake, and I have corrected it. Thanks it for great man. I am new to java and programming, I concatenate, but am confused how to implement in this case. Kindly extend your more help for concatenation here.